# Performance problems when using Gmail API to list threads

Tags: gmail-api

I'm running into major performance issues when trying to just get a list of the ten most recent threads in a user's inbox:

```
threads = gmail_client.users().threads().list(userId='me', maxResults=10, pageToken='', q='-in:chats ', labelIds=['INBOX']).execute()
```

This one query is consistently taking 5-6 seconds. Any idea what's going on here, or how I can speed this up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
threads = gmail_client.users().threads().list(userId='me', maxResults=10, labelIds=['INBOX']).execute()
```

There is no reason to send a empty pageToken, just omit the attribute. Also, chat messages aren't in inbox, no need to exclude them in the query.

Also, confirm performance is same across mailboxes, a busy mailbox is expected to be slower.

Comment: Thanks Jay. After more testing across inboxes the slowness seems to be not due to the query itself. (I initially thought it was because I had narrowed it down to this line, but all the other queries ran fine, including complicated batch queries.) For whatever reason it seems like all non-batch queries are really slow when run within Django, even when it's just one query like this. The same query runs fine when just run from within the quickstart.py script, so still not sure what's going on, I'm going to look into it further though.

Comment: After a little more investigation it doesn't look related to batch requests. Still looking into it.

Comment: After an excessive amount of investigation, this appears only to be an issue within vagrant. I actually tested the API call from a shell script inside vagrant and it was fine, but for some reason when the call is made from a Django app inside vagrant it's incredible slow. This was a fairly subtle issue, because requests directly to the Django API also perform fine, it was only traffic between Django and the web that's getting slowed down when inside vagrant. :-/